# same rearrangement for several excel files

Tags: r, excel, for-loop

I want make the same rearrangement for several files.xlsx, without doing it one by one.
I am able to make lists of dataframes, but not how to implement the FOR() function in the right way.

```
df <- read_excel("file.xlsx",  skip = 16)
rows <- nrow(df)         #1 eliminate last 22 rows
rowsfe <- rows-22        #1
rowse <- c(rowsfe:rows) #1
df <- df[-rowse,]       #1
df <-CF_dataframe[,colMeans(is.na(df))!=1]      #2 eliminate NULL columns
colNames(df) <-c("different","column","names")  #3 give the columns'names
df <-filter(df,Variable=="Level")               #4 filter for...
write_excel(df,"filenames.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly did your for loop attempt look like? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I attempt to write an excel file after the rearrangement done by code. With the help below i succeed. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vector of all the excel files, and use that to loop.

I also created an output folder for the modified excel files

I commented 2 of the lines, becasuse I think are specific to your files

make sure that your working directory is where your excel files are

hope it helps.

```
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)

dir.create("modified.excel.files") 
files.names=list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")

for(i in files.names){
    df <- read_excel(i,  skip = 16)
  rows <- nrow(df)         #1 eliminate last 22 rows
  rowsfe <- rows-22        #1
  rowse <- c(rowsfe:rows) #1
  df <- df[-rowse,]       #1
  # df <-CF_dataframe[,colMeans(is.na(df))!=1]      #2 eliminate NULL columns
  colnames(df) <-c("different","column","names")  #3 give the columns'names
  # df <-filter(df,Variable=="Level")               #4 filter for...
  write.xlsx(df, file = paste("modified.excel.files/modified",i))
}
```

Comment: you made the right work. Notice that file argument must be replaced with path. Thank you very much